# How to open a mdal popup in a browser window from webpage inside a IFrame

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe, modal-dialog, modalpopup

I have an ASP.net webpage named `"LiveChat.aspx"` within an IFrame.

From this webpage I want to open a modal popup (named `"DisplayChat.aspx"`) on the parent window outside the IFrame.

I have tried that with the following code but the modal popup gets opened inside an IFrame only.
So how to open a modal popup outside of an Iframe (i.e. on the parent website).I have tried with following code...

```
<a href="ChatDisplay.aspx?ChatRoomID=<%#Eval("CR_SerialNo")%>" style="color: #1d60ff" onclick="$(this).modal({width:650, height:500}).open(); return false;">
   <%#Eval("CR_ChatRoomName")%>
</a>
```

For this jQuery code I am using a online resource.
I have used `$(window.top)` instead of `$(this)`, but it does not open the modal popup on the parent window but shows the error that Resources isn't found. How can I overcome from problem?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

`onclick="$(this).modal({width:650,`

You can try this

`onclick="$(window.top).modal({width:650,`

to ask to open from the top window, and not from inside the iframe.

`window.top` or `parent` return the top of the browser, or the parent browser. So you can select one of this to call it and make on top. If this is not work, then make the same function on the top window, again using the `window.top` you can call it.

Comment: It shows the error that "resources not found".after using window.top instead of this

Comment: @user1659510 Then it seems that the javascript thats load your dialog is exist only on iframe. Move this function to parent window, and call it from parent